# find_or_initialize_by on has_many association causes duplicate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations, autosave

I'm seeing a strange error since I moved from Rails 3.0.11 to 3.1.3. Here's a standalone code to reproduce the error:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql2',
  :username => 'root',
  :database => "some_development"
)

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

u = User.create

# f = u.favorites.find_or_create_by_site_id(123)      #=> pass
f = u.favorites.find_or_initialize_by_site_id(123)    #=> fail
f.some_attr = 'foo'
f.save!

u.name = 'bar'
u.save!                # ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique will be thrown here!
```

will end up `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` attempting to `INSERT` the same record to the `favorites` table. (Note that with this example, (user_id, site_id) pair must be unique on favorites)

Interestingly, if I use `find_or_create` instead of `find_or_initialize` no exceptions are raised.

In the stack trace I noticed `autosave_association` gets called, don't know why, but actually `has_many :favorites, :autosave => false` instead of `has_many :favorites` removes the error, too. As I've never cared about `autosave`, I'm not even sure if `:autosave => false` is a good idea or not.

What am I doing wrong, or is it a Rails bug? Can anyone give me a pointer to look at?

Comment: Does the User model have a validation for uniqueness of a field?  Also what is that commented out line with `#=> pass` next to it?  Are you trying to create two versions of favorite at once or something?

Comment: Yes, the User model has a bunch of validations including uniqueness, though I'm not sure how it relates. If you comment-in the line of find_or_create instead of find_or_initialize, it should pass without an error, as described in my question.

Comment: Can you try this: instead of `u.save!`, do `u.save` and then `puts u.errors` or `p u.errors`.  What are the errors.  I have a feeling that this is an issue where you are creating a user which doesn't pass one of the validations for uniqueness (since you are using a generic `User.create` with no attributes being fed in).

Comment: Actually `u.save` raised the same exception as well. That is, it couldn't get to the following `puts u.errors`. Since it's a database level unique constraint, not a ruby level validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried not calling `f.save!` ? `u.save!` should save both favourites and users.

```
> f = u.favorites.find_or_initialize_by_site_id(123)

> u.favorites.include?(f)
==> false

> f2 = u.favorites.build(:site_id => 123)

> u.favorites.include?(f2)
==> true
```

I think what you find is that the new favourite `f` you have created is a separate object. Hence you will be saving f, while there is another un-saved favourite too in `u.favourites`. Hence a non-unique error occurs when you save u (which also saves the favourites)

I'm not sure if this is a bug newly introduced in Rails 3.1. It may be intentional.

In Rails 3.0 find_or_initialize_by did not populate the array

```
> f = u.favorites.find_or_initialize_by_site_id(123)

> u.favorites
==> []
```

Looks like a bug - see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3610

Comment: It has to be there because `u.save!` is at a distant place in the code from `f.save!`, and there's a chance that `u` is not dirtied and skip saving. I want to know the reason why it raises an error.